# How do I get the correct Inner HTML text with Javascript? I keep on getting a value of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a basic calculator. I seem to have done everything right. I am trying to get the buttons to show up on the screen as they are being pressed but I keep on getting an undefined value.

When I console.log the numbers. I get an array value. I have converted them to arrays and I see the correct innerText value but I still can't get them to display on my calculator display.

```js
'use strict'

const input = document.querySelector('.calculator-display');
const number = document.querySelectorAll('.number-buttons');
const numbers = Array.from(number)


numbers.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.value = number.innerText;

  });

});
```

```css
.calculator-display {
  height: 200px;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 7rem;
}

.operator-buttons {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.number-buttons {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="calculator-display" />
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="operator-buttons">*</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">/</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">-</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">+</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">.</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">9</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">8</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">7</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">6</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">5</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">4</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">3</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">2</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">1</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">0</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">=</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">DELETE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsFiddle link for this? Please

Comment: @RushabhWadkar — Stackoverflow supports inline live demos. There's no need to involve third party hosting.

Comment: Did you mean `button.innerText` instead of `number.innerText`?

Comment: btw where is `.calculator-display` in your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `number.innerText;` with `button.innerText;`. Pointed out by @Thomas also.

```js
'use strict'

const input = document.querySelector('.calculator-display');
const number = document.querySelectorAll('.number-buttons');
const numbers = Array.from(number)


numbers.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.value = button.innerText;

  });

});
```

```css
.calculator-display {
  height: 200px;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 7rem;
}

.operator-buttons {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.number-buttons {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="calculator-display" />
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="operator-buttons">*</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">/</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">-</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">+</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">.</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">9</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">8</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">7</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">6</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">5</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">4</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">3</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">2</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">1</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">0</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">=</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">DELETE</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`number` is [a node list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return), not an `<button>`. It doesn't have an `innerText` property.

The `<button>` that was just clicked on is stored in the `button` variable.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out to me. I changed the number.innerText to button.innerText and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The object you want the `innerText` from is part of the input parameter to the function the listener calls. You are trying to get `innerText` from `number` which is not a button object at all.  Try this:

```
numbers.forEach(button => {button.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (event.target) {
    input.value = event.target.innerText;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `input` text element? and replace to this `input.value = button.innerText;` inside the js method.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/pwnu51ft/33/) to playaround.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('.calculator-display');
const number = document.querySelectorAll('.number-buttons');
const numbers = Array.from(number)


numbers.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    input.value = button.innerText;
  })
});
```

```css
.calculator-display {
  height: 40px;
  width: 85%;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 3rem;
  color: red;
}

.operator-buttons {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}

.number-buttons {
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<input type="text" class="calculator-display">
  <button class="operator-buttons">*</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">/</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">-</button>
  <button class="operator-buttons">+</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">.</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">9</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">8</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">7</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">6</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">5</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">4</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">3</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">2</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">1</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">0</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">=</button>
  <button class="number-buttons">DELETE</button>
</div>
```